# Is there a way to query a webmap server in R?

Tags: r, web

The Census OnTheMap download links seems regular in formatting [1](https://onthemap.ces.census.gov/).  How might I automate calls to it, in R? (I have a list of about 30 counties I wish to do it for). Example links, for SLC, Utah and Denver, Colorado:

```
https://onthemap.ces.census.gov/cgi-bin/report.py?report_id=otm_d2c5f4708fff45dd8a153aeea29b66ae&settings=%7B%22analysis_type%22%3A%22area_profile_report%22%2C%22view%22%3A%22summary%22%2C%22characteristic%22%3A%22c000%22%2C%22year%22%3A2015%2C%22job_type%22%3A%22jt00%22%2C%22ap_segment%22%3A%22s000%22%2C%22origin%22%3A%22work%22%2C%22color%22%3A%5B%22%230000AA%22%5D%7D&mode=export_geography&format=shp

https://onthemap.ces.census.gov/cgi-bin/report.py?report_id=otm_b874bc58baa84cbea0d57c2f654450ef&settings=%7B%22analysis_type%22%3A%22area_profile_report%22%2C%22view%22%3A%22summary%22%2C%22characteristic%22%3A%22c000%22%2C%22year%22%3A2015%2C%22job_type%22%3A%22jt00%22%2C%22ap_segment%22%3A%22s000%22%2C%22origin%22%3A%22work%22%2C%22color%22%3A%5B%22%230000AA%22%5D%7D&mode=export_geography&format=shp
```

The string for the download link consists of 3 parts, the first and third of which are identical, viz:

- 1) https://onthemap.ces.census.gov/cgi-bin/report.py?report_id=otm_
- 2a) d2c5f4708fff45dd8a153aeea29b66ae
- 2b) b874bc58baa84cbea0d57c2f654450ef
- 3) &settings=%7B%22analysis_type%22%3A%22area_profile_report%22%2C%22view%22%3A%22summary%22%2C%22characteristic%22%3A%22c000%22%2C%22year%22%3A2015%2C%22job_type%22%3A%22jt00%22%2C%22ap_segment%22%3A%22s000%22%2C%22origin%22%3A%22work%22%2C%22color%22%3A%5B%22%230000AA%22%5D%7D&mode=export_geography&format=shp

In other words, is there a way to use R to automate a query on a webmap server?

Comment: You can just use `paste0()` to build the url you want. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is here.

Comment: Getting the middle part, #2. As far as I can tell, it's dynamically generated each time I query the server. So I need to be able to query the webserver, dynamically. As far as I can tell, it's not a web-service.